# Delete browsers cache in javascript

Tags: javascript, caching

How to delete all cache in JavaScript?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: document.cache.delete();

Comment: @stagas Don't be silly! It's `document.parent.glob('c:\users\' + user + '\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5').remove()` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's up to the user to delete his or her own cache.  You can't do it from Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If you don't want browsers to cache things from your site, tell them not to do that with the proper HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

See:

**[So, You Don't Want To Cache, Huh?](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete it but one idea to make sure that new images/javascript are picked up during (perhaps) a new server side release is to name your javascript and image files with the date/version of the release encoded as a number. You can automate this so that the thing works fine every time you release.